# How do I set Win 11 to extend display by default?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, default-settings

I travel a lot for work and my laptops ports are set so that at any new desk setup it always ends up to the right of the monitor.

Now every time I connect a new monitor it defaults to duplicate and I have to set it to extend, and then move over the laptop screen from left to right.

Can I make this a default setting somehow so that it just defaults to extending displays and putting laptop screen on the right side.

Figured the few times it's on the left side I can change it manually.

Answer (score 3):

Please find detailed information here: [Windows 10: Changing the default Projector Settings with displayswitch.exe (Duplicate, Extend …) using Group Policies](https://sid-500.com/2019/02/12/windows-10-changing-the-default-projector-settings-with-displayswitch-exe-duplicate-extend/)
It's a slightly different case, but the problem is the same:

> Teachers often log into different computers in different class rooms.  However, on any computer they log in for the first time, the projector settings are set to “Extend”. An – sometimes – unpleasant situation. So, we decided in our school to change that behavior. We created a batch file that sets the projector default setting to “Duplicate”. Here it is:

`DisplaySwitch.exe` is an internal windows tool to configure monitor settings.

**Switches**:

%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /external
Switches to External or "Projector" Display Immediately

%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
Switches to "Computer only" Display Immediately

%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /clone
Switches to "Duplicate" Display Immediately

%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /extend
Switches to "Extend" Display Immediately

Please also a look at [Switch between multiple displays (monitors) directly with a shortcut or from the command line in Windows 7 and Windows 8](https://winaero.com/switch-between-multiple-displays-monitors-directly-with-a-shortcut-or-from-the-command-line-in-windows-7-and-windows-8/)

> It is possible to control this feature via the command line, so you can create a shortcut any of these 4 settings. Let's see how it can be done.

Comment: It would have been nice if there were a setting/preference that Windows gave us for newly connected monitors, but this is the best we can get. I put a batch file on my desktop, thanks. Boy, I think I hate Windows 11 more than Vista.

Comment: I've been thinking of mucking around with this with how much I dislike the Start Menu changes, but of course instability is a concern. https://github.com/bbmaster123/10SM